# How to get upload speed in JAVA

Tags: java, android, tomcat, servlets

I am studying android app and I would like to build example code to check upload speed.

I already built upload speed check method, but I am not really sure if it is working correctly. This is because my method is returning upload speed even if android phone doesn't have proper internet connection

I built method like..

First, read 4.6 MB text file and then store into String variable

Second, Checking **start** time

Third, using post method and nameValuePair to send 4.6MB string variable to Google app engine(my google app engine. It is catching string data. it doesn't do anything.)

Fourth, Checking **End** Time

Lastly, Getting (Size of file) / (End Time - Start time) as uploading speed

here is my code...

```
public double Get_UPload_Speed() throws IOException{
    String file_path =("46.txt");
    File gone = new File(file_path);
    String line = "";
    double filesize = bts.Get_File_Size(file_path);
    int maxsize =  rf.Get_Total_Line(file_path);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(gone));

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://google.app.engine.address.com");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


    for(int index = 0 ; index < maxsize ; index++){
        if((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            // keep appending line of text to String buffer
            stringBuilder.append(line);         
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    String UL_Packet = stringBuilder.toString();
    double startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content",UL_Packet));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("guestbookName", "default"));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
            Log.d("UploadManager", "Upload Start: " + startTime + " secs");
        Log.d("UploadManager", "Upload End: " + endTime + " secs");
        Log.d("UploadManager", "Tranfer Time: " + tranferTime + " secs");
        Log.d("UploadManager", "Size of file " + filesize + " MB");
        double endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double tranferTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
        double rate = filesize/ tranferTime;         
        Log.d("UploadManager", "Upload speed: "+rate +" Mbps"); 
        return rate;
    }
```

However, I am not really sure if this is the right way to get upload speed.

Is there any solid way to build upload speed checking method ?

thanks

Comment: What is wrong with your solution, what results did you get?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use [Android TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) ?

```
/** Upload a random string and measure transfer speed */
public double Get_UPload_Speed()
    throws IOException
{
    int        MB         = 1;
    HttpPost   httpPost   = new HttpPost("http://google.app.engine.address.com");
    HttpClient httpClient = DefaultHttpClient();

    /** generate random string */
    char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
    StringBuilder sb     = new StringBuilder();
    Random        random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < MB*1024*1024; i++) {
        sb.append(
                chars[random.nextInt(chars.lenght)]);
    }

    long totalTxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes(); 
    long totalRxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
    double startTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();

    String UL_Packet = sb.toString();
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(
            new BasicNameValuePair("content",UL_Packet));
    nameValuePair.add(
            new BasicNameValuePair("guestbookName", "default"));
    httpPost.setEntity(
            new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

    httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    double endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double tranferTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;

    double rate = 
        (  TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - totalTxBytes
         + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - totalRxBytes) / tranferTime;         

    /** Log */
    Log.d("UploadManager", "Upload Start: " + startTime            );
    Log.d("UploadManager", "Upload End:   " + endTime              );
    Log.d("UploadManager", "Tranfer Time: " + tranferTime + " secs");
    Log.d("UploadManager", "Data size:    " + MB          + " MB  ");
    Log.d("UploadManager", "Upload speed: " + rate        + " MB/s"); 

    return rate;
}
```